# How to edit command line parameters of startup applications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager, msconfig

In older Windows versions, in MSConfig -> Startup tab you could edit the parameters of a startup application from the Command column.

Now in Windows 10, MSConfig moved the Startup tab to Task Manager, but you don't have any option to do the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which Startup applications, ones you added/installed? If their links are in the user startup folder at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` or the All Users folder at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`, then you may modify them.

Comment: Use SysInternals' [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) tool for to manage your startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you cannot edit the command line parameters of startup applications from Task Manager in Windows 10.

The easiest way to edit this information is via the excellent [SysInternals Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) tool, which also provides an interface to 17 other common ways in which you can automatically run a task on Windows startup.